# How to get array of strings to 'include' searching each keyword substring in every array element?

Tags: javascript

```
'service order'.includes('order')
```

returns `true`

but

```
['service orders','service','orders'].includes('order');
```

returns `false`

Open to ES2022 also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if a callback returns true for any element.

```js
console.log(['service orders','service','orders'].some(s => s.includes('order')));
```